# Special graph theory

Tags: graph-theory

Is there a sub-field of graph theory that deals with weighted, directed graphs where two nodes are either connected in both directions, or neither?

A simple real life application would be a hilly park with many trails and you want to find the fastest way to traverse all trails.

Comment: A directed graph with no one-way connections is just an undirected graph.

Comment: The weights are different from A->B than B->A.

Comment: It is just special form of a weighted directed graph.

Comment: @Fraukje: right, but are you aware of theorems that look at directed graph in a way that for example can solve the problem is finding an Eulerian path where is A->B is traversed then you don't need to traverse B->A ? Just like the question I asked about trails in a hilly park.

Comment: @BalazsRau I am not that into specific theorems, but to the best of my knowledge there is no special term for graphs as you describe.